# How to record a macro in sublime text 2?

Tags: macos, macros, sublimetext2

I am using sublime text 2 and want to record a macro for uploading the current file vie transmit docsend (super+u) and saving it locally (super+s).

So I start to record a macro ctrl+q and see the status notification in the footer

```
Starting to record macro ...
```

Then I hit super+s and it saves and the upload it vie super+u. After hitting ctrl+q for stopping macrorecording the footer says

```
Stopping recording macro
```

But I do not have the Option in the menu "Tools/Playback macro" and when I hit save Macro it doesnt do anything.

Any Idea?

PS: I am working on OS X and I have no directory

```
/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2
```

Have I to create it as admin?

Thanks a lot

Now I realized that I dont need the folder /Library... but ~/Library...

But after saving the File ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/User/transmit-upload-and-save.sublime-macro

```
[
{"command": "save"},
{"command": "transmit_docksend"}
]
```

and adding the following to user shortcuts

```
[
{ "keys": ["super+u"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/transmit-upload-and-save.sublime-macro"} }
]
```

it does not save but uploads ... whats wrong?

Answer (score 3):

To simply playback last recorded Macro press `Ctrl+Shift+q`. 
In Sublime Text2 Macros are not saved to file by default they reside in the macro buffer instead. 
 More [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html)

The reason it's uploading is because your key is only defined as `[super+u]` which is for upload - it should be `[super+s]` for save.

Hope that helps